# Flutter: Using the SlideTransition

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm confused on how to use the SlideTransition, especially about the Position property. Atm I've got an AnimationBuilder in which I want to use a SlideTransition and an AnimationController. How would I get the position of the child of the AnimationBuilder? Or is that not what has to be passed to the Position property?
Perhaps a small example would help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AnimationBuilder and SlideTransition are peers, you'd use one or the other (or both in parallel), you don't use one to use the other.

You want to create an `Animation<FractionalOffset>` from your `AnimationController`, typically using a `Tween<FractionalOffset>`.

See, e.g., https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/drawer_demo.dart

Comment: your link is dead